# Number of residues of perfect $k$-powers mod $k^2$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm curious about the number of possible values of $a^k \mod k^2$ for $k \geq 2$. Denote $$R_k = \{b \in \mathbb{Z}_{k^2} \mid \exists a \text{ s.t. } a^k \equiv b \pmod{k^2}\}$$ which is the set of possible residues of perfect $k$-powers modulo $k^2$. I became interested in this when I saw that $|R_k|$ tended to be small relative to $k^2$.

From computing $|R_k|$ on natural numbers $\leq 1000$, the value of $|R_k|$ appears highly variable, but there are patterns which crop up for particular values of $k$ (assuming I'm doing the calculations correctly). Here are some that I found interesting:

1. $|R_k| \leq k$.
2. If $k$ is prime, then $|R_k| = k$. If $k = p_1p_2 \dots p_n$ for distinct odd primes $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ for some $n \geq 2$, then $|R_k| = k$ if and only if for all $i,j$ where $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and $p_i > p_j$, $p_i \not \equiv 1 \pmod{p_j}$.
3. If $k = 2p$ for an odd prime $p$, then $|R_k| = p + 1$. If $k = 4p$ for an odd prime $p$, then $|R_k| = p + 1$ if and only if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.
4. If $k = p^m$ for an odd prime $p$, then $|R_k| = p^m - p^{m - 1} + 1$.
5. If $k = 2^m$ for $m > 1$, then $|R_k| = 2^{m - 2} + 1$.

(From my perspective these statements are only conjectures as I'm unsure if they are even true.)

There are many more patterns but I only wanted to list a few for this question. My question has two parts:

- What is the intuition/reason behind these patterns? I know $R_k - \{0\}$ is a group closed under multiplication, and I imagine this is partially responsible as some of these patterns resemble group-theoretic results.
- Which of these are even true?